# $\lim \frac{a_{2n}}{a_n}< \frac{1}{2}$ series convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you tell me how to prove such lemmas?

We are given a decreasing sequence of positive numbers $(a_n)$

1) If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{2n}}{a_n} =g< \frac{1}{2}$ then the series $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent

2)If $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{a_{2n}}{a_n} =G > \frac{1}{2}$ then the series $\sum _{n=1} ^{\infty} a_n$ is divergent

I know it must be very easy but I don't know what to do about $2n$ in $a_{2n}$ (which I gather is the main issue of the whole proof).

Do you think you could help me?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume you are talking about the convergence of $\sum a_n$. Start with [Cauchy Condensation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) Your problem will be a quick consequence. If the limit is $\lt 1/2$, then there is $\alpha\lt 1/2$ such that after a while the ratio is $\lt \alpha$. Or if you wish, instead of *using* Cauchy Condensation, you can imitate the proof.

Comment: He says "the series is convergent" which presumably means $\sum a_i$. But he is vague on the point. @Maesumi

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've already corrected my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look up the [Cauchy Condensation Test.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) Then either **use** the test, or **adapt** the proof.

Because it is faster, we *use* the test.  For example, for the first part, there is an $\alpha \lt \frac{1}{2}$ and an $N$ such that if $n \ge N$, then $\frac{a_{2n}}{a_n} \lt \alpha$.

But by Cauchy Condensation, $\sum a_k$ converges if and only if $\sum 2^k a_{2^k}$ converges. The latter  series converges by long run comparison with the geometric series $\sum (2\alpha)^k$.

**Remark:** Adapting the proof instead of using the result is a very good idea. One can then see that Condensation, which at first appears magical, comes from natural estimates.

Comment: I've already analysed the proof of the  Cauchy Condensation Test. But could you explain a little bit further how to use it for $\frac{a_{2n}}{a_n}$ ?

Comment: How to use the Test? Let $n$ be a large power of $2$, say $2^M$, and let $b=a_n$. Then for $j \ge M$, $a_{2^j}\lt b\alpha^{j-M}=b\alpha^{-M}\alpha^j$. Multiplying by $2^j$ gives us $\lt b\alpha^{-M}(2\alpha)^j$, the terms of a convergent geometric series.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. It's all clear now.

Answer (score 2):

Denote the partial sums by $S_n$. Now you can write 
\begin{align}
\sum_i a_i = S
&= S_n + (S_{2n}-S_{n}) + (S_{4n}-S_{2n}) + (S_{4n}-S_{2n})+\cdots \\
&= S_n + T_1 + T_2 + T_3+\cdots \\
\end{align}
To show that the series is convergent you easily get lower bounds of the form $c (2g)^k$ for $T_k$ in case 1) and upper bounds of the form $c (2G)^k$ for $T_k$ in case 2). (You have to make use of the fact that the $a_i$ are decreasing, too). So, in case one you've bounded your series with a convergent geometric series from above, and in case two with a divergent geometric series from below.

EDIT: Ok, I saw that this is pretty similar to the proof of the Cauchy condensation test, that has been mentioned by Andre already. I'll still leave it in here.